# How to mount all but some URLs to a single page?

Tags: wicket, single-page-application, wicket-6

I'm working on a single page application and want to mount arbitrary URLs my home page (Index.class), e.g.

```
/index
/home
/foo
/somethingelse
...
```

But some URLs should not be handled, to deliver static assets and access the REST api e.g.:

```
/api
/images
/css
```

So my question is, how to configure Wicket to route all but some special URLs to a single page. I guess I have to implement a custom RequestMapper and delegeate to the default one. Maybe something like this:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return Index.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        mount(new IRequestMapper() {
           // routing logic goes here
        });

        mountPage("/${page}", Index.class);
    }
}
```

additionally, I defined ${page} as an URL parameter to inject some config dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the entire picture of your code, but you could simply mount Wicket application to a different path (ex: /myapp) and use another one for static/REST resources.

Comment: That would be more of a workaround than a solution, wouldn't it?